# Does OCS inventory supports the remote WMI?

Tags: inventory-management

All the documentation of OCS Inventory says it must use client-side VBS scripts to serialize the information.

How can i use a remote WMI connection with OCS Inventory instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try fusioninventory-agent as it includes remote WMI support since 2.4 through the fusioninventory-wmi script.